# Inserting element in linked list after the biggest element in the list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I've been smashing my head here to see if I could find a solution but after few infinite loops, here's the code I'd like to be reviewed:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_TREE_STRING 100

typedef struct Node {
    char val;
    struct Node *next;
} node;

node *create_list(char *list_string) {
    node *momentary=NULL, *new=NULL, *head;
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<strlen(list_string); i++) {
        new = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        new->val = list_string[i];
        new->next = NULL;
        if (!momentary) head = new;
        else momentary->next = new;
        momentary = new;
    }
    return head;
}

int print_list(node *head) {
    node *momentary;

    if(!head) return -1;
    for(momentary=head; momentary!=NULL; momentary=momentary->next)
        printf("%c ", momentary->val);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}

node *find_biggest(node *head) {
    node *momentary=NULL, *biggest=head;

    if (head==NULL) return NULL;
    for (momentary=head; momentary!=NULL; momentary=momentary->next) {
        if (momentary->val > biggest->val) biggest = momentary;

    }

    return biggest;
}

void insert_after_biggest(node **head, node **biggest, char val) {

    node *p = *head, *temp=NULL;

    *head = p->next;


    if(*head!=NULL){

        if(p->val==(*biggest)->val){

            temp=p;
            p->next=temp;
            p->val=temp->val;

            p->next=NULL;

            *biggest=p;
            p->next=(*biggest);
            p->val=(*biggest)->val;
            //*biggest=p;

            p->next=NULL;

            //temp=p;
            p->next=temp;
            p->val=temp->val;

        }

        else if(p->val<(*biggest)->val){

            *head = p->next;

            }
    }

}

int main () {
    node *head=NULL, *biggest=NULL;
    int menu_choice;
    char c, val, list_string[MAX_TREE_STRING];

    setbuf(stdout, NULL);
    do {
        menu_choice = 0;
        printf("\n1 Create list \n2 Print");
        printf("\n3 Insert after biggest");
        printf("\n4 exit\n");
        scanf("%d", &menu_choice);
        switch (menu_choice) {
            case 1:
                if (head) {
                    printf("List exist.\n");
                    break;
                }
                printf("Enter list as digits without spaces: ");
                scanf(" %s", list_string);
                head = create_list(list_string);
                break;
            case 2:
                print_list(head);
                break;
            case 3:
                scanf(" %c", &val);
                insert_after_biggest(&head, &biggest, val);
                break;
            case 4:
                break;
            default:
                while((c=getchar())!='\n' && c!=EOF);
        }
    } while(menu_choice!=4);
    return 0;
}
```

> Now the task here is:
>
> Write a function "insert_after_biggest" so that the new elements are
>   put behind the element with the highest value and complexity of the
>   function must be O (1). In other words, the function "find_biggest"
>   that has complexity of O (n) can be called only if the "biggest" has
>   not yet been defined. If the list has no elements , it still needs to
>   be first.
>
> Here's a console example to have clearer picture:
>
> 1|<-Insert into linked list option| 
>   Enter list as digits without spaces: 683 |<-Prompt and entered value| 
>   3 |<-Option(the function)|
>   2 |<-Number to be inserted|
>   2 |<-Print option|
>   6 8 2 3|<-Output|
>   3 |<-Option|
>   8 |<-Number to be inserted|
>   2 |<-Print option|
>   8 |<-Output|

I've been typing this code myself and I have no idea anymore how to look at this.
I would humbly ask if someone can help me to solve this, the code compiles but executing the option 3 in the console only makes it run in infinite loop, resulting in crashing the console.

The specific: how to solve it (step by step) and how it should look like(the done code, possibly included here?).

Thank you.

Comment: this code is too large; there is no need for special cases, when using double pointers.

Comment: @wildplasser I still need the if-s for going trough the list. Or could you clarify more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can assume that

1) You don't need to remove elements

You merely need to keep an extra pointer that points to the node with the largest value at all times.  It's nice that you are allowed to scan the list for the largest if you've never called 
insert_after_biggest, but that's not even necessary.  Call that node max, and the pointer to max p_max.

For each insertion

a) The value you're about to insert is larger than the value held by max, in which case you insert the new value, and change p_max = p_new.

```
n_new->next = p_max;
p_max = p_new;
```

b) The value you're about to insert is larger than the value held buy max, in which case  simply insert and leave p_max unchanged.

For insert_after_max
you explicitly do

```
p_new->next = p_max->next;
p_max->next = p_new;
```

Or if the new value is larger then do as described above.

Since you don't have to scan the list to insert, the complexity of insertion is O(1)